# Reassign an event emitter in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom-events, mqtt, eventemitter

I'm using the MQTT npm module.
When fires the `myMqttObj.on('close',...)` event I call `myMqttObj.end()` and then reassign it with a new connection:

```
 myMqttObj= mqtt.connect(....)
```

In this way all the previous `myMqttObj.on()` methods are listening on the new emitter. **All this works great**.

Now I'm trying to create my own method to create a new MQTT connection with the same npm module. I want only to hide the MQTT connection parameter calling a custom method with a simple string as a parameter:

```
var mySDK= require('./mySDK');
mySDK.mqttConnect("input",function(_inMqtt){
    if(_inMqtt!=null){
        inMqtt=_inMqtt;  //inMqtt is a global variable

        inMqtt.on('connect', function() {
           //do something here
        });

        inMqtt.on('close', function() {
            inMqtt.end();
            mySDK.mqttConnect("input",function(_inMqtt){
                inMqtt=_inMqtt;  //this assignment to the same Client object doesn't work
            });
        });
});
```

the `mqttConnect` method simply call the `mqtt.connect` method and return the Client object.

I expect that all the `inMqtt.on()` function are now listening on the new Client object, instead **no event is catched**. 
What's the problem?

Comment: "*reassign it with a new connection: `myMqttObj = mqtt.connect(....)`. In this way all the previous myMqttObj.on() methods are listening on the new emitter*" That's absolut non-standard behaviour. An new object, a new instance, always means new listeners to be initialised. If you have not misinterpreted what you're seeing, they're doing really dodgy things - or the call isn't actually creating a new instance, but returns the old one. This should be documented in their API.

Comment: Yes, it's strange, and now I think that it's right it doesn't work.. I've solved creating new listeners with the new object